# copy and move files in /data/ using root access

Tags: java, android, android-studio, root

I want to delete, copy and move some files in `/data/data/...`  folder using root access.
How can I do it?

For example, I want to access this  `/data/data/.../files/TEST)` and move it to `/SD/My-Application`.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any samples or helps to do this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Well you can use the same code as always. Why would it be different?

Comment: Really?I don't think so.I think it is different.Can you give an example if they are the same?I want to copy from 
"/data/data/com.example.tes1/files/1.jpg" to "/data/data/com.example.tes2/files/2.jpg".

Comment: Can you first explain why you think that it is different? What would be the problem? Tell the problem you encoutered! Why didn't you already?

Comment: You know I'm beginner, first I used to code with B4A but it had some problems, specially in BroadcastReceiver, so I decided to learn JAVA :). In Basic4Android the codes were different (it needed a library). It's because of that.If you give me an example I will appropriate that :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I searched a lot but I couldn't find any samples or helps to do this.`. All very strange. You did not google for android copy file ?